# Colour contrast for large areas of colour

Tags: colors, accessibility

There are a few tools available for testing colour contrast for text. But are there any guidelines/tools to test colour contrast for areas of colour, e.g. bars in a stacked bar graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colour contrast rules are there to ensure that users with low-vision or colour-vision impairment can still distinguish different elements. For a graph, I'd be doing two things:

1) Test the page on a colour-blindness simulator. I use [Vischeck](http://www.vischeck.com/vischeck/) but I'm sure there's others out there.

2) Back up the use of colour with another method of distinguishing between bars - pattern and labelling come to mind. If the graph is an image, you can also give it a caption that summarises the data.

You could still use something like the [Color Contrast Analyser](http://www.paciellogroup.com/resources/contrast-analyser.html) for a graph. For each bar, use the foreground eyedropper to sample it, then the background eye-dropper to sample the background *and* the columns to either side.

Answer (score 0):

From AccessiWeb 2.1 reference list (based on WCAG 2.0), here's a relevant criteria:

> [Criterion 10.14](http://www.braillenet.org/accessibilite/referentiel-aw21-en/index.php#crit-10-14) (Bronze = Level A)
>   On each Web page, information must not be provided by its shape or location alone. Does this rule have been followed?

WCAG 2.0 sufficient technique(s) and/or failure(s) related to it are:

- [G96](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/G96.html) Providing textual identification of items that otherwise rely only on sensory information to be understood
- [G111](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/G111.html) Using color and pattern
- [F14](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/F14.html) Failure of Success Criterion 1.3.3 (*) due to identifying content only by its shape or location
- [F26](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/F26.html) Failure of Success Criterion 1.3.3 (*) due to using a graphical symbol alone to convey information

(*) [1.3.3 Sensory Characteristics](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#content-structure-separation-understanding): Instructions provided for understanding and operating content do not rely solely on sensory characteristics of components such as shape, size, visual location, orientation, or sound. (Level A)